# How can I hear micromusic.net on Android?

Tags: internet-radio

If I start micromusic.net in chrome or Firefox on my nexus, I can't hear the music.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternative browser like [FlashFox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.browser.flashfox). Its selling point is the fact that it plays flash.

Source: Installed FlashFox, opened a random channel on micromusic.net, there were sounds!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean www.micromusic.net?
It seems that the site uses Flash to play the music, which is not supported on Android at all. You'd have to get the developers of the site to provide other options for listening to the stream.

Comment: So isn't there a plugin then for flash or another browser I could use that works on www.micromusic.net?